# Optional property based on value of enum

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings

I'm trying to get some typings to work for a react `useReducer`.

Basically I have an action that has an optional property (`data`) based on the value of another property - so if `STATUS` is `VIEW` or `EDIT`, the action must have the `data` property. I almost have something working, but there's one case (see below) where this fails.

I guess one way of doing this is by explicitly setting `STATUS.NEW` to not require the extra property (`{ type: 'SET_STATUS'; status: STATUS.NEW }`), but I'm wondering if theres a better way. If in the future I added a bunch of different statuses then I'd have to specify each one to not require the data property.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=35&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=1#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)

```
enum STATUS {
    NEW = 'new',
    VIEW = 'view',
    EDIT = 'edit'
}

/*
    if status is 'view', or 'edit', action should also contain
    a field called 'data'
*/
type Action =
    | { type: 'SET_STATUS'; status: STATUS }
    | { type: 'SET_STATUS'; status: STATUS.VIEW | STATUS.EDIT; data: string; }


// example actions

// CORRECT - is valid action
const a1: Action = { type: 'SET_STATUS', status: STATUS.NEW }

// CORRECT - is a valid action
const a2: Action = { type: 'SET_STATUS', status: STATUS.VIEW, data: 'foo' }

// FAILS - should throw an error because `data` property should be required
const a3: Action = { type: 'SET_STATUS', status: STATUS.EDIT }

// CORRECT - should throw error because data is not required if status is new
const a4: Action = { type: 'SET_STATUS', status: STATUS.NEW, data: 'foo' }
```

And the second part of the question is how I'd incorporate this into a `useCallback` below. I would have thought that useCallback would be able to correctly infer the arguments into the appropriate action type.

```
/* 
    assume:
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(stateReducer, initialState)
*/

const setStatus = useCallback(
    (payload: Omit<Action, 'type'>) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_STATUS', ...payload }),
    [],
)

/* 
complains about:

Argument of type '{ status: STATUS.EDIT; data: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<Action, "status">'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'data' does not exist in type 'Pick<Action, "status">'
*/
setStatus({ status: STATUS.EDIT, data: 'foo' })
```

Comment: For the second part it would be easier if you could create separate question with simple reproduce in playground like you did for the first part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of statues that require `data`, then [exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu) them in action representing all the others:

```
enum STATUS {
    NEW = 'new',
    VIEW = 'view',
    EDIT = 'edit'
}

type WithDataStatuses = STATUS.VIEW | STATUS.EDIT;

type Action =
    | { type: 'SET_STATUS'; status: Exclude<STATUS, WithDataStatuses> }
    | {
        type: 'SET_STATUS';
        status: WithDataStatuses;
        data: string;
    }

// now CORRECT - data is required
const a3: Action = { type: 'SET_STATUS', status: STATUS.EDIT }
```

Comment: Ahh, it's `Exclude`! I was doing `Omit<STATUS ...`. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Answer for second part of question :-)

Assuming that you have defined `Actions` as suggested by @Aleksey L., `useCallback` can by typed as follows

```
// This is overloaded function which can take data or not depending of status
interface Callback {
  (payload: { status: Exclude<STATUS, WithDataStatuses> }): void;
  (payload: { status: WithDataStatuses; data: string; } ): void;
}

const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(stateReducer, {})
// Explicitly type useCallback with Callback interface
const setStatus = React.useCallback<Callback>(
  (payload) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_STATUS', ...payload }),
  [],
)
setStatus({ status: STATUS.EDIT, data: 'foo' })
setStatus({ status: STATUS.NEW })
```

The working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/usereducer-typing-oigc1)